# Importing .shp Files Into R: readOGR error

Tags: r, rgdal

I'm trying to import shapefiles into R but receiving errors. I'm using rgdal package and doing the following:

```
x <- readOGR(".", "SNP Basefile")
```

> Error in ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding,
>   use_iconv = use_iconv,  :  Cannot open layer

I used dsn="." since I had placed the shapefile in the current working directory. "SNP Basefile.shp" is the shapefile I'm trying to import.

Comment: Please use list.files(".") to see for sure all the required files are there

Comment: Maybe possible a problem with the space on the name, will try later

Comment: I suggest just loading the file, the way you load a raster:   readOGR("Path to file")